Bounded almost surely indicates existence of real boundary?
Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. Suppose that $$\mathbb{P}(\limsup \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}} < \infty) = 1.$$
a) Show that there exists $C > 0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}} \leq C) = 1.$
b) Show that $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] < \infty$ (hint: Borel-Cantelli's lemmas).
Both parts are related.
For a), I said that $\limsup \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}} < \infty$ almost surely, i.e., $\limsup \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ is bounded almost surely. Thus, $\forall \omega \in \Omega$, there exists $C(\omega)$ such that $$\limsup \frac{|X_n(\omega)|}{\sqrt{n}} \leq C(\omega) < \infty.$$ Then, choose $C = \sup\{C(\omega), \omega \in \Omega\}$ to get desired result.
Not sure this is rigorous.
For b), I don't see how Borel-Cantelli's lemmas are useful here (conditions on sum of probabilities indicate infinitely often or not, not sure how this relates to the mean of second moment).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

$C$ may be $\infty$.

For every $C>0$, by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, $P(\limsup n^{-1/2}X_n\leq C)\in\{0,1\}$. Continuity of measure implies there is a finite $C$ so that $P(\limsup n^{-1/2}X_n\leq C)=1$. By scaling, we may assume $C=1$. Next, $X_1\in L^2$ if and only if $\sum P(X_1^2>n)$ is finite. By the i.i.d. assumption, this is the same as asking whether $P(X_n^2>n)$ is summable. By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the answer is necessarily yes, for otherwise it would imply $P(X_n^2>n \text{ i.o.})=1$, contrary to the result of part (a).

Thanks, this seems like exactly what I was looking for. I do have a few questions about some statements.


"Continuity of measure implies there is a finite $C$ so that $P(\limsup n^{-1/2}X_n\leq C)=1$." Can you clarify this part? (maybe in an edit?)


"Next, $X_1\in L^2$ if and only if $\sum P(X_1^2>n)$ is finite." Same question, why is this the case?


The rest is clear!

@WilliamLe $P(Y<\infty)=P(\cup_m {Y<m})=\lim_m P(Y<m)$. If $Y\geq 0$, then Tonelli's theorem gives $E[Y]=E\int_0^Y dt = \int_0^\infty P(Y>t)dt$.
